# Alexa oauth refresh_token and invalid_grant response

Tags: oauth-2.0, alexa-skills-kit

I'm using [OAuth2 Server PHP](https://github.com/bshaffer/oauth2-server-php) to handle the token authorization from Amazon Alexa for my skill.

I noticed that on regular basis Alexa asks the users to deactivate and reactive the skill.

What is happening:

1. Alexa sends a POST to my Token.php page with
   `{"grant_type":"refresh_token","refresh_token":"3673c55124f61d8fxyz37a315bb0296de","client_id":"alexa"}` and a "Authorization" header that contains the `client_id` and the `client_secret`
2. My server will return an error 400 with
   `{"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"Refresh token has expired"}`
3. The user receives an error from Alexa asking to reactivate the skill…

I'd expect for Alexa to send a new request to the server to get a new token, but this is not happening.

What am I missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I posted this question on three different places (here, oauth2-server-php Github, and Amazon Alexa forum), but no answer…

As a "fix" I did the below in my `server.php`:

```php
$server->addGrantType(new OAuth2\GrantType\RefreshToken($storage, [
  'always_issue_new_refresh_token' => false,
  'unset_refresh_token_after_use'  => false
]));
```

And I changed [`RefreshToken.php`](https://github.com/bshaffer/oauth2-server-php/blob/5a0c8000d4763b276919e2106f54eddda6bc50fa/src/OAuth2/GrantType/RefreshToken.php#L86-L90) by removing this part of the code:

```php
if ($refreshToken['expires'] > 0 && $refreshToken["expires"] < time()) {
    $response->setError(400, 'invalid_grant', 'Refresh token has expired');
    return null;
}
```

Until I get a better answer/explanation :-)